# how to automate dragndrop using cypress plugin

Tags: jquery, cypress, drag

not able to drag the first task in my list to 3 task

```
cy.get('div[data-columns="columns"]')
      .find('div[data-columnContainer="columnContainer"]')
      .each(($column) => {
        if ($column.text().includes("Hamza Malik")) {
          cy.get('div[data-taskDraggable="taskDraggable"]:nth-child(1)').drag('div[data-taskDraggable="taskDraggable"]:nth-child(3)', { force: true });
        }
      });
```

Comment: i have wrote a new code but not using the plugin but still its not working


`
   cy.get('div[handle-task="handleTask"]').eq(0)
      .trigger('mousedown', 1, 1, { force: true })
      .trigger('mousemove', 0, 100, { force: true })
      .trigger('mouseup');

`

Answer (score 3):

There is the `trigger()` command for simple situations, the example is [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/trigger#jQuery-UI-Sortable)

```js
cy.get('div[data-columns="columns"]')
  .contains('div[data-columnContainer="columnContainer"]', 'Hamza Malik')
  .find('[data-cy=draggable]')
  .trigger('mousedown', { which: 1, pageX: 600, pageY: 100 })
  .trigger('mousemove', { which: 1, pageX: 600, pageY: 600 })
  .trigger('mouseup')
```

But this means some calculation of x-y points which is not ideal, and can break if the page layout changes.

Since you already use `cypress-drag-drop`, I suggest the selectors need changing. The code that finds your name is not affecting the drag operation.

I think using `.within()` gives you better results:

```js
cy.get('div[data-columns="columns"]')
  .contains('div[data-columnContainer="columnContainer"]', 'Hamza Malik')
  .within(() => {

    // Now queries operate within the specified container column

    cy.get('div[data-taskDraggable="taskDraggable"])
      .then(draggables => {
        cy.wrap(draggables.eq(0))   // drag first over third
          .drag(draggables.eq(2))
      })
  })
```